# Force test to fail when Selector finds more matching elements

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, frontend, testcafe

TestCafe usually works with first matching element and it doesn't mind when you use non-unique selector for element. Is there a way how to force an error when this happens without writing count assertion on every Selector?

Emaple HTML page:

1. Coffee
2. Tea
3. Milk

- Coffee
- Tea
- Milk

Selector `Selector('li').withText('Coffee')` would in this case with some error like "Selector matches multiple elements."

Answer (score 1):

The [.withText](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402740/reference/test-api/selector/withtext) method is not supposed to throw such an error. It's only designed to find elements that match some text. Then, you can [get the number](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402755/reference/test-api/selector/count) of matched elements, take [the nth one](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402748/reference/test-api/selector/nth), or [filter](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402753/reference/test-api/selector/filter) them with some custom conditions. That error is unexpected behavior for the .withText method.